# First time making a recipe!

Tags: extract, ipa, recipe-formulation, americanipa

So I decided to throw some ingrediants together for my first recipe! The recipe is an extract American IPA I was wondering if some of you guys could give me advice on what to add or get rid of before I brew it. If you could help it would be great!

Thanks

American IPA
Extract (5.00 gal) ABV: 5.47 %
OG: 1.056 SG FG: 1.015 SG
IBUs: 67.7 IBUs Color: 12.3 SRM
By: 
Ingredients

1 lb 8.0 oz - Vienna Malt
Steep prior to boil (14.3%) - 3.5 SRM

1 lb - Caramel/Crystal Malt - 20L
Steep prior to boil (9.5%) - 20.0 SRM

5 lb - Amber Liquid Extract
Boil (47.6%) - 12.5 SRM

3 lb - Amber Dry Extract
Boil (28.6%) - 12.5 SRM

1.00 oz - Simcoe
Boil 60 min (40.2 IBUs)

0.50 oz - Summit
Boil 30 min (20.2 IBUs)

1.00 oz - Citra
Boil 5 min (7.4 IBUs)

0.50 oz - Summit
Boil 0 min (0.0 IBUs)

1 pkg - American Ale II
Wyeast Labs #1272

Comment: The numbers look right. I thought you might be a little heavy on the crystal, but after some research it seems people vary from 0%-15% of the grain bill. I haven't done an IPA yet, but I used about 6% grain bill Crystal 20L in an American Pale, and I could taste it. So it would be up to your taste preference on that.

Answer (score 1):

I'd get rid of everything where you don't know why it's in the recipe. As a beginning brewer, I try to keep my ingredients to a bare minimum (1 lme/dme, 1 steeping grain, 1 hop, 1 yeast) when making my own recipes (ok, I made a triple-hop ale but the hops I stole from Duvel so that doesn't count). Also, I "develop" my recipes on a site with a built-in calculator (I use Brewer's Friend) which can sort of give a rough indication whether my beer is in style. I find that very helpful.

KISS.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that Vienna malt needs to be mashed.  Although if you steep it for 45-60 min. at about 150F, that will be pretty much the same as mashing.  Also, amber extract will have crystal and other malts already added to it.  I'd recommend using the lightest extract you can find, preferably dry, then add your own specialty malts.

Answer (score 0):

There's no right or wrong here, but it struck me that this recipe will produce a relatively dark wort for an IPA, and your results might be a bit more on the malty side than most IPAs tend to be.  If that's what you're going for, great! Otherwise, you might consider replacing the amber extracts with pale versions.

Also, is there a good reason to use both LME and DME?  You might simplify things a bit by picking just one or the other.